# Arch kills USB Stick on write

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, arch-linux

Every time I copy stuff to my pendrive, 0 Bytes get written.
Step by step:

```
$ dmesg | tail   
 ... as sdb1 ...   
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt   
$ mount | grep /dev/sdb1   
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437, iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)  
$ cp /path/to/file /mnt   
(1-2 seconds pause)
```

After that, the prompt shows up again, indicating the command has finished.

But:

```
$ df -h   
(All my mounts EXCEPT /dev/sdb1)

$ umount /dev/sdb1   
Special device /dev/sdb1 not found   
(Unplugging the drive and reconnecting it)   
$ dmesg | tail   
... as sdc1 ...   
$ mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt   
$ ls -al /mnt/file   
rwxrwxrwx user group 0 file
```

Why does it only copy the index, but never the file? No change even after 30 minutes.
On a sidenote, every non-root user gets a "Permission denied" when trieing to write anything. May be related.

Add 1:

```
[ 3505.951652] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7488) failed
[ 3505.951658] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7489) failed
[ 3505.951662] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7490) failed
[ 3505.951666] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7491) failed
[ 3505.951671] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7492) failed
[ 3505.951675] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7493) failed
[ 3505.951679] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7494) failed
[ 3505.951683] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7495) failed
[ 3505.951687] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7496) failed
[ 3505.951691] FAT-fs (sdb1): Directory bread(block 7497) failed
[ 3505.952401] FAT-fs (sdb1): FAT read failed (blocknr 203)
[ 3536.704292] fat__get_entry: 246 callbacks suppressed
```

Happens after copying files to the device. I tried several thumbdrives.

Add 2:
An rsync -av log as user

```
sending incremental file list
file
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/.file.09oDMm" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 303,348,282 bytes  received 119 bytes  86,670,971.71 bytes/sec
total size is 303,274,124  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1189) [sender=3.1.3]
```

The same operation as root:

```
sending incremental file list
file
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/.file.tVJ2Th" failed: Input/output error (5)

sent 303,348,282 bytes  received 119 bytes  202,232,267.33 bytes/sec
total size is 303,274,124  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1189) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Add 3:
fsck on the drive after rsync-ing to it while clean

```
$ fsck /dev/sdb1                   
fsck from util-linux 2.33
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/file
  Contains a free cluster (6032). Assuming EOF.
/file
  File size is 303274124 bytes, cluster chain length is 0 bytes.
  Truncating file to 0 bytes.
Reclaimed 9256 unused clusters (303300608 bytes).
Free cluster summary wrong (457661 vs. really 466917)
1) Correct
2) Don't correct
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/sdb1: 2066 files, 6534/473451 clusters
```

It most certainly is an error on my pendrive nevertheless, as another pendrive (NTFS) works just fine...

Comment: What does `mount | grep /dev/sdb1` show after you mount the device?

Comment: @choroba I edited my answer. Additionally, here you are:   

/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: What happens when you do `cp /path/to/file /mnt/` instead (note the trailing slash)?

Comment: @dirkt It doesn't change anything, but now every file gives me an I/O-Error

Comment: When is "Add 1" from? Should look at the syslog (probably /var/log/syslog) & dmesg after mounting & after writing, might show what's breaking things, and maybe what's broken. And even if everything were working 100%, if it's mounted rw and you just yank it out without unmounting then things will probably get broken. [I had nothing but trouble with FAT on usb's, switching to ext3/4 made them virtually bulletproof]

Comment: Looks like the USB stick has read errors in directory areas. What happens if you don't mount, but try to copy, say, the first 10M with `dd` from `sdb1` to some local file?

Comment: @Xen2050 Add 1 is my dmesg after copying files. I didn't get the oportunity to check that stepwise though, so it might as well be a read.

Comment: @dirkt It runs smoothly, nothing from dd, nothing from dmesg.

Comment: @Xen2050 I only remove the drive in mounted state when I can't unmount it in any other way. My syslog is not there mysteriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to finally close this question: Indeed my usb drive was dead. Twice. Never buying SiliconMotion controllers again.